# Parsing xml with quoted inner xml declarations

Tags: java, xml, string, parsing, javax

I'm trying to parse xml files provided to me. I'm parsing the files using javax.xml DocumentBuilder. The files can contain tags that have quoted inner xml which I do not want parsed.

Shortened example:

```
<Property Name="Value" PreFormatted="1">"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16'?>"</Property>
```

When I run the parser as so:

```
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
    .newDocumentBuilder()
    .parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("utf-8"))));
```

I receive the following error:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:106: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is
                      not allowed.
```

I understand that this error occurs when you have more than one xml declaration in the code, but I am unable to figure out how to prevent the parser from attempting to parse the quoted xml.

How can I prevent quoted xml from being parsed?

Comment: That is illegal XML.  You can't parse it.

Comment: You will have to go back to whomever gave you that XML and tell them that it's wrong.  The quotation marks should be done with entities (`&quot;`), not with `"` itself..

Comment: Yea, that's what I figured out. Apache commons has a method StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10 which I used to escape the special characters...

Apparently there is an issue escaping single quotes with &apos; however. I had to manually use StringUtils.replace.

Thank you.